# How to remove value from GAE NDB Property (type BlobKeyProperty)

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

It might be the most dumb question and my apologies for the same but I am confused

I have the following entity:

```
class Profile(ndb.Model):  
    name = ndb.StringProperty()  
    identifier = ndb.StringProperty()  
    pic = ndb.BlobKeyProperty() # stores the key to the profile picture blob
```

I want to delete the "pic" property value of the above entity so that it should look as fresh as if "pic" was never assigned any value. I do not intend to delete the complete entity. Is the below approach correct:

```
qry = Profile.query(Profile.identifier==identifier) 
result_record_list = qry.fetch()  
if result_record_list:  
    result_record_list[0].pic.delete()  # or result_record_list[0].pic = none # or undefined or null
```

I am deleting the actual blob referred by this blob key separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assign None to it and put it back to the datastore.

```
result_record_list[0].pic = None
result_record_list[0].put()
```

Comment: Thanks omair_77 for your reply

Answer (score 1):

The datastore is an OO schemaless databse. So you can add and remove properties from the the Kind (ndb.Model) without the need of a schema update.

If you also want to cleanup the entities look at [this anwser from Guido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694569/how-to-cleanly-remove-ndb-properties)

Comment: Thanks voscausa for your reply