# Google App engine renaming fields in ndb datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to rename some field names in my model, i have copied the data from old field to new field. Now i want to delete the old fields. is there any convenient way of doing this ?

there is a method described
[here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema)

for removing the fields in db datastore, will it work for ndb datastore as well ?

Comment: the db and ndb datastores work on the same underlying db, it's just the interface that differs. So it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as mentioned, both db and ndb are using the same Datastore service.
see [how to cleanly remove ndb properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694569/how-to-cleanly-remove-ndb-properties) for another way of removing an old property.
You could have done the copy and removal in one pass to save datastore operations.